# SQL server management studio review script like MySQL Workbanch

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench, you are able to preview a script before it is applied. Ex:

1.) Select * from any_table
2.) Modify one a value in one of the rows returned
3.) Click apply
4.) you are presented with a review script dialogue before it is applied (See image)

Does SQL Server Management Studio have similar functionality

[image]

Comment: What did it look like before you hit Review? That looks like a regular query in SSMS. Were you using a graphical query builder and this is the script preview?

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty similar to the following SQL Server Management Studio functionality:
From the SQL Server Management Studio object explorer window, right click on a table then:
"Script Table as"
"Update to"
"New Query Editor Window"

Comment: Define your definition of "similar".  He asked about similar functionality, not identical functionality.  If you feel there is some option that is more "similar" or exactly the same in SSMS, feel free to submit an answer about it.

Comment: He wants to know if SSMS will generate the update statement once a value is edited in a Grid like his screenshot shows. Not what you've shown. The answer is no. SSMS will only confirm the `UPDATE` if you right click a table and click 'Edit Top 200 rows` and update 1 row. It won't show the confirmation with the actual `UPDATE` SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: no there is nothing that allows you to view the scripted out edit of live data similar to that. The best SSMS has to offer is the "edit top 200 rows" option and then editing the SQL behind it to accomodate for where clauses etc...

It will automically script out and **run** the script right when you make the data change. But there is not really a "Review" piece to it.

Would be nice though...